# Speedometer in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to show a speedometer on a page, whose status will be based on the value passed to it.
I came across JQuery Speedometer plugin at http://plugins.jquery.com/project/speedometer, but i couldnt find the download link for the same.

Please help
Thank You.

Comment: its seems that link is broken you can try the link posted by me

Answer (score 3):

Check out this **[speedometer](http://windyroad.org/2007/04/13/javascript-speedometer-poc/)** created using Javascript/css and some **[analog clocks](http://randomibis.com/coolclock/)** in Javascript/css as well.

Answer (score 0):

http://plugins.jquery.com/node/14456
download the jquery for Speedometer